# How to upload in-memory image with Tweepy?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tweepy

I am manipulating images in Python using `PIL`, and I want to upload it to Twitter via `Tweepy`. I can save the `PIL` image to disk and upload that file with Tweepy just fine, but I'd rather directly upload the image in-memory to be more efficient. How do I achieve this?

Here is a simple example of saving the image to a disk that works:

```py
from PIL import Image
import tweepy

# Example image manipulation
img = Image.open("input.jpg")

# Do something to the image...

# Save image to disk
img.save("output.jpg")

# Setup Tweepy API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key="", consumer_secret="")
auth.set_access_token(key="", secret="")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Upload media to Twitter
ret = api.media_upload("output.jpg")

# Attach returned media id to a tweet
api.update_status(media_ids=[ret.media_id_string], status="hello world")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing this self-answer post, as I found uploading an in-memory file with tweepy to be rather poorly explained. Tweepy docs for [API.media_upload()](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.media_upload) and [API.simple_upload()](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.simple_upload) for reference.

---

### Answer

After some digging, I found a code snippet that works from [this closed issue on github](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1412). Here is my answer based on that post:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tweepy

# Example image manipulation
img = Image.open("input.jpg")

# Do something to the image...

# Save image in-memory
b = BytesIO()
im.save(b, "PNG")
b.seek(0)

# Setup Tweepy API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key="", consumer_secret="")
auth.set_access_token(key="", secret="")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Upload media to Twitter APIv1.1
ret = api.media_upload(filename="dummy_string", file=b)

# Attach media to tweet
api.update_status(media_ids=[ret.media_id_string], status="hello world")
```

---

#### Additional Notes

##### Required filename parameter for `API.media_upload()` and `API.simple_upload()`

Both `API.media_upload()` and `API.simple_upload()` requires you to provide a string to the parameter `filename` even if you are uploading in-memory. The string can be anything, even an empty string, and the upload still seems to work. *(Tested on Tweepy v4.4.0)*

---

##### `b.seek(0)` is required for Tweepy >= v4.0.0

Another note is that `b.seek(0)` is necessary for Tweepy v4.0.0 and above, according to [this other github thread.](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1667#issuecomment-927342823) If you don't perform the seek operation, Twitter will respond with a `400 Bad Request`.

However, you can also seek to some other parts of the stream to begin uploading from there instead of from the beginning, if you know what you're doing.

---

##### BytesIO

In the [github issue I found the answer from](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1412), they used this slightly different snippet:

```py
...

b = io.BytesIO()
img.save(b, "PNG")
b.seek(0)
fp = io.BufferedReader(b)

media = api.media_upload('test.png', file=fp)
```

Both this version and the one above worked just fine for uploading images, so I'm not certain what `io.BufferedReader()` does.